# Перенос символа на новую строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как сделать перенос символа на новую строку ?.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно сделать группу из любого символа

```
(.)
```

и поменять на такое

```
\1\r\n
```

Comment: Это '(.)' на это '\1\r\n' помогло - спасибо! Верхнее ваше что то c 'S' и 'R' мудрило.
Не знал как группу отловить, теперь знаю, спасибо!

Comment: \R - любые переносы строк \r или \n. А где вы S увидели - не знаю

Comment: попробуйте на моём примере - своё предложение -
S и R оставались на одной строке, всё остальное как нужно.

Comment: Да, вы правы, так его использовать нельзя